# Mustache JS with Json iteration

Tags: json, mustache

I am new to Mustache and I'm running into some issues

My JSON looks like following

```
var Views = {
  "$id": "11",
  "name": "Life",
  "id": "Life_932",
  "createdDate": "12/01/2017",
  "updatedDate": "12/01/2017",
  "defaultView": false,
  "background": "#1395C6",
  "share": {
    "accessType": 82007,
    "specificUsers": [
      {
        "users": "872",
        "permission": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "shared": true,
  "dashletUserId": 932,
  "Username": "ZAM"
}


var temp = '<div class="menuContainer">' +
              '<div class="createCopytxt {{#shared}}disableClass{{/shared}}"><span class="createCopy"></span>Create Copy</div>' +
              '<div class="renameDashboardtxt {{#shared}}disableClass{{/shared}}"><span class="renameDashboard"></span>Rename</div>' +
              '<div class="deleteDashboardtxt {{#shared}}disableClass{{/shared}}"><span class="deleteDashboard"></span>Delete</div>' +
              '<div class="defaultDashboardtxt"><span class="defaultDashboard"></span>Set as Default</div>' +
           '</div>' +

var out = Mustache.render(template, Views);
```

I want to disable the classname createCopytxt,renameDashboardtxt and  deleteDashboardtxt based on the permission of users.Currently it is based on the shared value.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Only include the class if the property "shared" is truthy.

```
<div class="{{#shared}}renameDashboardtxt{{/shared}}"><span class="renameDashboard"></span>Rename</div>
```

If you want to actually replace createCopytxt/renameDashboardtxt/deleteDashboardtxt with disableClass, you can do:

```
<div class="{{#shared}}renameDashboardtxt{{/shared}}{{^shared}}disableClass{{/shared}}"><span class="renameDashboard"></span>Rename</div>
```

Check out the Mustache docs, specifically the "inverted" section: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: Share JSON structure is given below :-   "share": {
    "accessType": 82007,
    "specificUsers": [
      {
        "users": "872",
        "permission": 1
      }
    ]
  } I have to display this when the specific user permission is 1 only.